# Grafana Column no value suggestion in query builder

Tags: postgresql, multiple-columns, grafana

I am using Grafana for visualisation for my Mariadb and Postgres databases. On Mariadb, there are suggestions in the query builder for the column row but not on Postgres. If I type the name myself, it shows the data correctly but no suggestion is shown. Can anyone help?

[image: Grafana no Value suggestion in query builder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any suitable column (numeric type, e.g. int, float, ...) in `zf1_table` table, so that's a reason why editor is not offering any column in the select section.

Or very likely you don't have proper permissions: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/postgres/#database-user-permissions-important

So used Grafana DB user can't read table structure.

Comment: The table has 32 columns. If i type the name of the column explicitely the graph shows up

Comment: @S.A. see update

Comment: Thanky to your comment i fount the bug. Grafana does not read numeric types from postgres. I needet to change the numeric to double/float